The hat from \widehat{X} rotates by 90 degree when using packages MnSymbol and amssymb. Why? Can I keep unrotated while still using those packages?
A full small example:
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}  
$\widehat{X}$ 
\end{document}

Screenshot from output: [![rotated hat][1]][1]
The hat from \widehat{X} rotates by 90 degree when using packages MnSymbol and amssymb. Why? Can I keep unrotated while still using those packages?

that is clearly not the default setting, so in code you have not shown something is wrong. show a small complete document that produces the output shown and show the full log including any error messages

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\widehat{X_{YZ}}^{-1}$
\end{document}`  produces this output

@DavidCarlisle You are right. I have just noticed that even with $\widehat{X}$ the hat is rotated in my setting. Do you know which setting will change this behaviour? I use a template from institute, and I do not know the exact thing of settings.

@YH Either you give us some way to create a rotated hat on our machine, or you give us access to your machine. (The former is preferable.)

How can we guess if you show no code????? Perhaps you have redefined widehat to use \rotatebox ro rotate itself and the answer is don't do that. Obviously there is no standard setting to produce the output you show

This is probably due to conflicting math font packages. Without an example it's very difficult to say.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for the answer. I find the reason why widehat is rotated in my latex program is using package amssymb, i.e \documentclass{article}  \usepackage{amsmath}  \usepackage{amssymb}  \begin{document}  $\widehat{X_{YZ}}^{-1}$ \end{document} produces the rotated output. Deleting \usepackage{amssymb} would solve the problem. Any other solution to make the widehat unrotated, while keeping using the package amssymb?

@YH the code in your comment produces this output please edit the question to give a full small document that shows the problem and show the full log file

@DavidCarlisle I have completely edited the question to give a full small document that shows the problem. The log file is too long to show the full (if I understand correctly what the log file is), so I take possibly a large part of the log file.

MnSymbol.sty well that is definitely not used by the example in your comment above, did you try that example at all?

mnsymbol and amssymb are alternatives that use different encodings to set up the math fonts it makes no sense to load both packages, choose one or the other

@DavidCarlisle I tried that. It seems that I cannot find the log file for the current example in overleaf, so I delete the log file now. The problem is solved, I just use assymb package for now.

The log file was fine, what I meant was that your comment above where you give a test file just using amssymb was presumably completely false and untestesd

Problem solved. As is described in the comment of the question, it makes no sense to load both packages MnSymbol and amssymb. I just use assymb package for now, and the hat keeps unrotated.
